# camel modifying header of split from inside aggregation strategy

Tags: apache-camel

Is it possible to modify a header that was set coming into aggregationstrategy

split messages
setheader groupname to "one"
aggregate on correlationkey header -groupname=one

The aggregation strategy will know at some point that it wants to change the correlation key to something else. But if i set the groupname on the header of the incoming new exchange, it is not creating a new correlationkey

How can I accomplish this ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change correlation key inside the `AggregationStrategy` neither in the Splitter EIP or the Aggregate EIP.

The correlation key is determined beforehand using the correlationExpression you set on those EIPs.

The `AggregationStrategy` is used for merging the exchanges together.

See more details on the Camel EIP documentation of these patterns, or check some of the Camel books such as Camel in Action which has extensive coverage of these EIPs